# Rails checkbox and field_with_errors issue

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

Yo! So I am running into an issue and I've narrowed it down to this. I am using a custom bootstrap [checkbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes). It works fine. Except. When I click submit without checking it and get my error message it will not let me click on the checkbox and try and submit again. What I've narrowed down the issue to is that the `div` `field_with_errors` is wrapping around my checkbox input and my label so my label no longer sees the checkbox input and thus it will not let me check it.

So my question is has anyone run into this issue and what did you do to solve it? Any recommendations would be great. I'm not looking to do anything to hacky.

Here is the code in question.

```
<div class="form-row mt-5">
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <%= f.check_box :iarf_consent, class: 'custom-control-input', id: 'allocation_consent_iarf_consent' %>
      <%= f.label :iarf_consent, "I have read and agree with the Terms and Conditions", class: "custom-control-label", id: 'allocation_consent_iarf_consent'%>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is how the html looks after the error messages

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
   <input name="allocation_consent[iarf_consent]" type="hidden" value="0">
   <div class="field_with_errors">
      <input class="custom-control-input" id="allocation_consent_iarf_consent" type="checkbox" value="1" name="allocation_consent[iarf_consent]">
   </div>

   <div class="field_with_errors">
       <label class="custom-control-label" id="allocation_consent_iarf_consent" for="allocation_consent_iarf_consent">I have read and agree with the Terms and Conditions
       </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

And to be clear I narrowed down that this was the issue by adding divs around my checkbox and label and seeing that I could no longer click the custom checkbox. Thanks for any help.

UPDATE:

I've narrowed the issue even further. It appears that clicking the label does its job. It just doesn't visually show up. Using some JS I can see that clicking the label does in fact check the checkbox it just isn't visible on the custom checkbox being used. I am thinking I can trick it to show up as clicked with some jquery. Seems kinda weird to do it. I'd like to understand why this is happening and how the bootstrap custom checkbox works. If anyone has any insight that'd be sick.

Comment: The input should work as expected even if label and input are in the separate divs (thanks to `for` attribute for the label and `id` for input, [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/m5ao0v8h/)).
Maybe you have JS code that prevents input from being checked? Or there is another element that covers the input/label?

Comment: @MrShemek hmmm I don't think there is any js code preventing it. I legitimately don't know what is causing the issue. I just know when I put a div around either the checkbox or the label it doesn't work. And I know when I get errors the input and label get wrapped in divs with the class name `field_with_errors`. Thanks for the input though

Comment: @MrShemek I do believe it is something with the bootstrap custom checkbox that is causing the issue. So that is why your example doesn't directly help me. I know if I use a normal checkbox it will work. Might have to go with that route instead of using this custom checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being my solution to the issue.

```
var mergeFieldWithErrorsForCustomCheckbox = function () {
  var fields = $('.custom-checkbox .field_with_errors');
  fields.first().append(fields.not(':first').children())
  fields.not(":first").remove();
}
```

I just merged the two `field_with_errors` divs so then the checkbox would work. My intuition tells me there might've been an issue with the classes and the css rules we had in place. Either way this was my solution.

Comment: @Tashows haha I agree it was kind of hacky but I couldn't figure out anything else. Glad to hear it worked for you!

Answer (score -1):

You can disable `.field_with_errors` generation using an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/field-with_errors.rb
# Disable field_with_errors entirely

ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  html_tag
end
```

Comment: This does not resolve the issue, since everyone still needs these generated for errors.